# PHP retrieveing from SQL but forgetting linebreaks?

Tags: php, sql, line-breaks

I'm using a Textarea element to allow users to update their "status".

All works fine but new lines disapear when I retrieve the text from the SQL? It SAVES them ok, and I can see them in PhpMyAdmin, but when I run this code after retrieving all the updates:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($StatusResult))
{
  echo $row['Text'];
  if (GetLoggedOnId() == $_GET["UId"])
  {
    echo "<form>
          <input type=\"submit\" value=\"X\" name=\"REMOVE\"/>
          </form>";
  }
  echo "<br/>";
}
```

it seems to just "forget" where linebreaks were.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this method when printing the string: [nl2br](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php)

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure whether to accept your answer or Arjan's, since you both gave a working answer at almost the same time.. :/. Wish we could accept two.

Comment: Do what feels the best for you. Glad I could help.

Comment: I suppose I'll go with Baszz, since he has less reputation.

Answer (score 3):

HTML ignores newline characters. Use `nl2br()` to convert the newline characters to `<br>` breaks that will display as expected in HTML.